# How to set a variable in another function with jQuery

Tags: jquery

All,
I have the following code:

```
jQuery('#posts-container-infinite').infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : "div.pagination",
                       // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
        nextSelector : "a.pagination-next",
                       // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector : "div.post",
                       // selector for all items you'll retrieve
        errorCallback: function() {
            jQuery('#posts-container').isotope('reLayout');
        },        
        path: function(){
            desturl = '';
            return desturl;
        }
    }
```

I'm clicking on a link to do some filtering for an isotope. This code is this:

```
jQuery('.blog-tabs a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
});
```

Is there a way within my `click` function to set the `desturl` variable within my function `jQuery('#posts-container-infinite').infinitescroll({`?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm..how about creating a global variable that changes in that click function, and set the `desturl` to that variable?

Comment: Agreed.  I don't think it's possible, nor should it be, to affect the value of a private variable in another method.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var desturl =''; //create a variable desturl  here 
jQuery('#posts-container-infinite').infinitescroll({
    navSelector: "div.pagination",
    nextSelector: "a.pagination-next",
    itemSelector: "div.post",
    errorCallback: function () {
        jQuery('#posts-container').isotope('reLayout');
    },
    path: function () {
        return desturl; //use value here
    }
}
jQuery('.blog-tabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector
    });
    desturl='test'; //assign value here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basic variable scoping. Variables that have been declared within a function are only available within that function block (or child functions). Declare the variable on the block level each of your desired functions to use that variable are:

```
var desturl;

jQuery('#posts-container-infinite').infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : "div.pagination",
                       // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
        nextSelector : "a.pagination-next",
                       // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector : "div.post",
                       // selector for all items you'll retrieve
        errorCallback: function() {
            jQuery('#posts-container').isotope('reLayout');
        },        
        path: function(){
            desturl = '';
            return desturl;
        }
    }

jQuery('.blog-tabs a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
});
```

doing this you can access and change the variable in both functions